# Java variable not saving in database

Tags: java, mysql

I want to store six variables 3 are integers and three are of string data type, here is my prepared statement code

```
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement("insert into mydb (firstInt, firstString, secondString, secondInt, thirdInt, thirdString ) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    stmt.setInt(1, firstInt);
    stmt.setString(2, firstString);
    stmt.setString(3, secondString);
    stmt.setInt(4, secondInt);
    stmt.setInt(5, thirdInt);
    stmt.setString(6, thirdString);
    stmt.executeUpdate();
```

The problem is string and integer type variables are not storing in database. What is wrong with this code?

Comment: Are you committing the transaction? Does it give any error?

Comment: Can you edit this and add how you are making the connection?

Comment: Please include the entire connection logic.

Comment: Damn sure, there is something wrong in connection script as the above code is syntactically Correct.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are not committing the transaction and autocommit might be set as false at database level. Please check your code and db settings.

Comment: Not an answer, better a comment

Comment: Then, the gentleman ought to not answer till he **can** comment.